# Update linked fields in access

Tags: ms-access

I have a form that contains a continuous subform that is linked with ID,Date and Shift fields.

ID is not changable in mainform. but date and shift fields can be changed.

The problem is when i change the value of Shift or Date in mainform the corresponding values are not being updated.

**EDIT**
I made a query to refresh the table of continuos form. It works. But i need to use this code in mainform.

UPDATE SubTable, MainTable SET SubTable.[Date] = [MainTable].[Date], SubTable.[Shift] = [MainTable].[Shift]
WHERE (((SubTable.ID)=[MainTable].[ID]));

Comment: i think i will get no help again.

Comment: Can you give more background to what you are trying to do? I would imagine that the two forms would be linked by one filed only, say ID. Also I can't picture why you have a contimuous subform with fileds that simply repeat (in each record) data in the main form. Perhaps I misunderstand.

Comment: @ÖmerBuluş You didn't get a response in 14 minutes and started complaining... the free help you get didn't respond fast enough... and you started complaining.   Please try to expand on your question to make sure we have a clear picture of what you are trying to do and also say what you have tried.

Comment: dont take it as a complaint i have written the same question two days ago and there was no reply also. i know its free help and i thank all of you anyway. it was because im stuck at somewhere in a Project that i need to finish for work. and im a newbie for sql. thats why i was impatience. sorry.

Comment: i have a mainform containing fields ID, Date and Shift. And i have a continuous sub form that is linked to main form with those three fields. because i want the date and shift field to be in the all records of the subform. but when i link those two forms; while changing the field in main form, the records in the subform is not being updated.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation I think you just didn't get an answer last time because you updated another question which no one would ever see.  People on this website are fantastic for helping you just need to make sure your questions are clear and concise.   Also please make sure you put your updates to the question in your main body so it doesn't get buried in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to link the two forms only by a single field. In My scenario I created a field on the sub table called "MainLookup" (Integer). This links to field "ID" on the main form. Changes are made to Date and Shift in the main form. If you were to create a query based on the sub and main you would have only one record of Dates and shifts for each ID. Looking at forms, I created a Main form and a sub form linked ID:MainLookup. The sub form only shows data in the sub table, but the Date and Shift data are intact and as recorded on the main form.

Comment: I have a complex query thats why the date and shift fields must also be at the subform. now i try to update table that contains subform records with the after update event procedure. but im not really good at coding

Comment: Can we see the query?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bo87ap81eog792j/Verimlilik.mdb?dl=0 here is the link for the database.

Comment: i made a seperate query to check mainform table and subform table ids. if they are equal the date and shift fields are being updated from mainform table and written to subfrom table. but i dont know how to use this is afterupdate procedure

Comment: So you have a query that shows data from your main form and sub form and that dat is correct? What do you want to do next?

Comment: no the query i built is an update query. i need to implent this code to the form

Comment: Can you show me the update query? Can you clarify "i need to implent this code to the form"?

Comment: I have now seen the query. Obviously you have fields 'Date' and 'Shift' in each table. Why is this? Also 'Date' is a Reserved Word and should be changed e.g. to 'MyDate'.